# Why is it not recommended to nest fluid containers?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I used Bootstrap to make my website's layout. In a page's content, there are widgets. Those widget has their own structure of div, table, span, etc. and does not use bootstrap to position themselves. Some of those widget have a template to display data. I want to use bootstrap in that template.

It actually works perfectly when I do so, but it's clearly written in the documentation not to nest containers. Why?

http://jsbin.com/xokodonajo/1/

As you can see, without nesting a container, my row will expend beyond its parent. This is usually countered by equivalent padding from the container.

Should I ignore the warning? Is the warning only meant direct nesting? Will I run into troubles in the long run?

Comment: "Clearly written in the documentation not to nest containers." It is? I've never read that. As far as I know, you can nest them if you want, but it shouldn't be necessary. Using the `row` class should be all you need after making a `container` or `container-fluid`

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#overview-container "Note that, due to padding and more, neither container is nestable."

Comment: Hmm. I guess I'm just blind :P But anyway, I'm working on an answer to show that you don't need nested containers for the example you posted.

Comment: Keep in mind that the div with the pink border cannot have a bootstrap class. It's a 3rd party widget that I do not have complete control over (a Kendo grid to be more specific).

Answer (score 1):

I think it may have been over complicated. This should be all you need.

```
<div class="container-fluid" style="border:2px solid red">
  <div class="row" style="border:2px solid yellow">
    <div class="col-sm-12" style="border:2px solid green">
      <!-- Some Widget -->
      <div class="kendo-grid" style="border:2px solid pink">
        <div>This is a widget</div>
        <div>Widget Templated Data</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm unfamiliar with the output of a `kendo-grid`, but if it's simply a `<div>`, you only need to place it inside a `col-*-*` class to have it align correctly within the `container-fluid`. Check this Bootply to see what I'm talking about.

[Bootply Example](http://www.bootply.com/nUJJGxHdkw)

On the subject of nesting `container` classes, it is possible, but shouldn't be necessary if you use the `row` and `col-*-*` classes as they're intended.

Hope that helps!

**Edit**

The other alternative is to add the `Widget Template Data` to another row, like so:

```
<div class="container-fluid" style="border:2px solid red">
  <div class="row" style="border:2px solid yellow">
    <div class="col-sm-12" style="border:2px solid green">
      <div class="kendogrid" style="border:2px solid pink">
        <div>This is a widget</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row" style="border:2px solid yellow">
    <div class="col-sm-12" style="border:2px solid green">
      <div style="border:2px solid pink">
        <div>Widget Templated Data</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the update Bootply:

[Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/Qf5TsJnLoC)

Comment: The point was to align stuff in the templated data. Your first answer doesn't do that at all. The 2nd answer is not doable with the widget. I really need nesting. Theres no way around it.

Comment: Odd. The issue is I just don't know the structure/return of a kendogrid is and made assumptions on where it could be used. If you can get the nesting to work, go for it. As long as you're not violating anything and the HTML renders with no errors you should be fine to use it. Sorry I couldn't help more.

Comment: Well first of all, it uses tables so that's already annoying :) http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/detailtemplate Assume the grid detail (the expended information within the grid) is just a div that I make a template for. Also assume that the grid is wrapped in a layout built with Bootstrap. The details template is where I'm trying to use Bootstrap but would result in nesting conflict.